# Is the redragon m601 good for drag clicking?

Tags: gaming, mice

So, I am thinking of getting a better gaming mouse under 20$ which could get me good cps. This is as I would like to learn breezily, and godbridging in minecraft bedwars.

I have currently seen only redragon phaser m609 and m601, and I have seen some youtube tutorials on how to drag click on m601, but I am unsure that if this is my best choice. If anyone could recommend me a better mouse, it would be really helpful.

Also, I don't know if I can ask these type of questions here, if I can't, then please tell me where can I, and I will ask this question there.

I live in India, and I am okay with price range of under 2000 inr. Also, I would prefer mice present on Amazon/Flipkart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bought the M601 redragon mouse, and it seems to be working perfectly for its price. I get around 17-20 short dragging and 25-30 long dragging. I know you have probably bought a mouse given that you asked this 8months ago. Although I would recommend the m601.
*Tips for more cps:*
**Make** sure your fingers aren't wet-moist when drag clicking.
**Tape** could help although I managed to get 30+cps without it.
**You** could use the adhesive of sticky tape, dab it on the mouse buttons and it should help.
**The** more you use the mouse the better cps you get, for example out of the box I could just get 17long drag.
I hope this could help, I'm really late to answer your questions I just started to use this website.

Happy New Year!!

Comment: You can find the M601 redragon mouse, on Amazon.

Comment: I can answer any other questions of yours regarding bridging or PVP with the mouse

Comment: SIDE NOTE: I'm really close to mastering god bridge, I know how to moonwalk and breezily. I can't telly bridge though. CPS when PVPing can help to make sure the extra CPS can guarantee and hit. But you don't need high CPS for combo's.

Comment: When butterfly clicking left click I get around 14-17CPS as I double click on the M601 aswell. I don't jitter click but I have seen people get the same CPS as butterfly clicking on the M601. On my main answer I say what I get for drag clicking.

Comment: I already bought an offbeat wireless mouse by the time you answered, but given your response, I will make sure to purchase the M601 as my next mouse. Thanks for the answer though.