# Best gaming mouse for drag clicking under 60$ (4400 inr)

Tags: gaming, mice

My question is what is the best gaming mouse that can drag click/ butterfly high cps for godbridging available on amazon.in. I am okay with any mouse that can get me high rmb cps under 60$ as of now in 2021. I live in India, so please recommend mice that are available to buy them in India.

Comment: Duplicate of [Is the redragon m601 good for drag clicking?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14841/is-the-redragon-m601-good-for-drag-clicking)

Comment: @Salocor I was the one who asked that question as well, but no one answered it in this community, so I thought making a general question instead of comparing b/w two specific mice would be better.